# Please Help Me Learn to Fish - Javascript, Prototype and XML

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, prototypejs

I am looking for a good online reference to working with XML in Javascript.  Specifically, I am using the protoype library. I have my ajax response with a valid responseXML document.

I can find all sorts of online examples for looking at the data in the first child node of the first element tagged 'X', but that doesn't help me.  What I need to know how to do is to find all elements tagged 'X' and then look at the values of several different child nodes of each of these elements, and then based on that information, manipulate them with javascript.

So, I need a more in depth resource of examples using Javascript and XML, ideally within the context of prototype.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to learn about XPath. Here is a nice [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

Comment: This helped quite a bit.  I also found some scraps of information in other places. I am now able to cycle through my data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question - it sounds like you need to read a book or two.

I would search a bookstore for "prototype javascript" or "prototype javascript ajax".

This book may be a good one, assuming that Barnes and Noble's link does not break:

[Prototype and Scriptaculous in Action](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Prototype-and-Scriptaculous-in-Action/Dave-Crane/e/9781933988030/?itm=1&usri=1)

One of the authors is the same author of jQuery in Action which I found to be a spectacular book.

Comment: I'm hoping to find similar content online as I've exhausted my book budget for the month.  Thanks for the suggestion though. I will keep this one in mind for my next book purchase.